# zeros of $x^*Ax$, a quadratic form

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, quadratic-forms, matrix-decomposition

The question hopefully says it all!

We have a Hermitian matrix $A=A^* \in \mathbb{C}^n$ and a quadratic form: $f(x)=x^*Ax,~x\in \mathbb{C}^n$

We want to find the solution of $f(x) = x^*Ax = 0$

When the matrix is positive semi definite (p.s.d.), the solution seems to be *null-space* of the matrix of $A$. This I found by diagonalising $A$. But suddenly I became helpless when $A$ has negative Eigen values too!

Please note that when the matrix is not p.s.d., the solution space contains the null space. (I.e. null space is always a solution)

Comment: Have you tried solving this in the case that $A$ is diagonal?

Comment: In fact, it suffices to solve this in the case that $A$ has elements $\pm 1$ and $0$.

Comment: @omnomnomnom Thanks for the comment. That's exactly where my solution stage is. This tri element diagonal case gives me an equation with no further insights!

Comment: For example, the solution for the matrix $$\pmatrix{1\\&1\\&&-1}$$ is the cone $x^2+y^2=z^2$. Note that this is not a linear subspace.

Answer (score 5):

Consider $N\times N$ matrices and $N\times 1$ vectors. Let $A=U\Lambda U^H$ be its eigen-decomposition. Then
\begin{align}
x^HAx &=y^H\Lambda y && \{\text{where I define }y=Ux,~\forall x \} \\
      &=\sum_{i=1}^{N}|y_i|^2\lambda_i \\
      &= \theta^T\lambda        
\end{align}
where $\lambda$ is the vector with all eigenvalues and $\theta$ is any vector whose entries are non-negative. Thus, for any  $\theta\in\left(\mathcal{N}(\lambda)\cap\mathbb{R}_{+}^N\right)$ where $\mathcal{N}(\lambda)$ is the null-space of $\lambda$ vector (set of all vectors orthogonal to $\lambda$) and the non-negative $N$-dimensional orthant (non-negative quadrant where all entries are non-negative), we have $\theta^T\lambda=0$. Now consider the set $\mathcal{D}$ of all diagonal matrices such that the diagonal entries lie on the unit circle in the complex plane. Then your solution set is 
\begin{align}
\mathcal{S}_x\,=\,\{U^HD\sqrt{\theta} \,\mid\,\forall D\in\mathcal{D}~,~\forall \theta\in\left(\mathcal{N}(\lambda)\cap\mathbb{R}_{+}^N\right) \}
\end{align}
where $\sqrt{\theta}$ is the entry-wise square root of $\theta$.
$\mathcal{D}$ is needed because it doesn't matter what the phase of each entry of $y$ is. Note that $y_{i}=D_{ii}\sqrt{\theta_i}$ and $|y_i|^2=|D_{ii}|^2\theta_i=\theta_i$. The difficult part is that $\mathcal{S}_x$ is not a linear subspace and you won't have that nice properties. It is a highly non-linear transformation and I am not sure what intuitive sense you can derive out of it.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. This does give a good insight.

But $\mathcal{N}(\lambda)\bigcap\mathbb{R}_{+}^{N}$ is not the solution of $y$ (but a solution of $y\cdot^* y$), let alone desired $x$! (The question actually asks about $x$, as the zeros of the quadratic $x^*Ax$) 

Ofcourse, $y$ is a simple but non-linear mapping from $\mathcal{N}(\lambda)\bigcap\mathbb{R}_{+}^{N}$. But there is another unitary transformation to be applied after this non-linear transform. What does that all finally mean, is the mystery still!

Comment: You are right. It is far from stating the answer. I thought the reverse transformation is obvious. I have now explicitly stated it.

Answer (score 0):

The set $C$ of solutions of $x^*Ax=0$ is a cone that contains the null space $N$ of $A$, i.e. the set of solutions of $Ax=0$.

This cone $C$ need not be a subspace in general.
E.g. take $A$ diagonal with eigenvalues $(1,1,-1)$, then $C$ is the cone in the complex $3$-space given by $|z_1|^2+|z_2|^2-|z_3|^2=0$.

When $A$ is positive semidefinite, then $C$ coincides with the subspace $N$ as correctly stated. This fact is purely algebraic and can be proved without diagolization, in particular, also when $A$ is an operator in an infinite-dimensional space. The proof is based on using the associated hermitian form $h(x,y)=x^*Ay$ and the computation

$$0\le h(cx+y,cx+y)= |c|^2 h(x,x) + 2\Re(c h(x,y)) + h(y,y),$$

where $c$ is any complex number.
Then if $y\in C$, i.e. $h(y,y)=0$, the right-hand side is $0$ for $c=0$ and nonnegative for all $c$, hence $0$ is a local minimum and the partial derivatives at $0$ with respect to the real and imaginary parts of $c$ must be zero. The latter is only possible when $h(x,y)=0$ for all $x$, which is equivalent to $y\in N$.