# Solving $x^\dagger A_ix=0$ , $x^\dagger x=1$

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations, quadratics, quadratic-forms, quantum-mechanics

How to solve the system
$$x^\dagger A_ix=0$$
$$x^\dagger x=1$$
where $x\in\mathbb{C}^n$ and $\{A_1, A_2,... A_m\}, A_i\in\mathbb{C}^{n\times n}$ is a given set of $m>n$ complex symmetric matrices?

We can write $x^\dagger A_ix=0 \implies x\in Ker(A_i)$ or $x \perp A_ix$ but I have hard time figuring out what the second case means.
I also looked into quadratic programming libraries but I don't see how to deal with the fact that we have a system of equations and not only one quadratic form.

Comment: A quick clarification: you have $A_{1},\ldots,A_{n}$ matrices and $x\in\mathbb{R}^{n}$? In that case, if $x\inKer(A_{i})$ then $x$ belongs to the eigenspace of the zero eigenvalue of each $A_{i}$. So you can take the interserction of all the eigenspaces.

Comment: You may be interested in the following: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1198427/zeros-of-xax-a-quadratic-form

Comment: @Pedro It is not true that every such $x$ lies in the intersection in the kernels. In particular, if $A$ is neither positive nor negative semidefinite, then it is possible to have $x \in \Bbb C^n$ such that $x^\dagger A x = 0$ but $Ax \neq 0$.

Comment: Also, presumably you mean Hermitian matrices @Nichola?

Comment: @BenGrossmann but if $x\inKer(A_{i})$ then that would be the case, right?

Comment: @PedroIgnacioMartinezBruera the point is being in the kernel is a sufficient but not necessary condition.

Comment: @BenGrossmann the A are complex symmetric, not hermitian